# Cohomology of punctured surface

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a compact oriented surface without boundary, $p$ is a point on $M$. Whether does the conclusion hold: $H^1(M-\{p\}) \cong R$ ? If yes, how to prove it (or please kindly point me to a reference)?

Comment: I don't think this is true for any compact oriented surface. It's true for $\mathbb R^2$, but certainly not the sphere or the torus, and the other surfaces will have even bigger $H^1$ than the torus with a point removed (or maybe the same, that's where my expertise off the top of my head ends).

Comment: You will probably want to argue using a Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I misunderstood the contents of textbook.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt Samuel says as a comment, this is not true.

Take $M=S^2$, then $S^2-p\simeq D^2\simeq \ast$ (seen through a stereographic projection), so $\widetilde{H}^i(S^2-p; A)=0$ for all $i\geq0$ and all abelian groups $A$.

Other counter-examples include a genus $g$ surface $M_g$, which can be built as in page 51 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book (see https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), and we can then see that 
$$M_g-p\simeq \bigvee_{2g} S^1,$$
which is the wedge sum of $2g$-many 1-spheres. Then we immediately get
$$H^1(M_g-p;A)\cong\bigoplus_{2g}A,$$
for any abelian group $A$.

In fact, by the classification of compact oriented surfaces, the result never holds for such spaces.